# Ordering RXJS streams by data property

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-observables

I have an issue where I'm attempting to order multiple distinct streams from a time series database. Assuming that all the data in each stream is sorted by timestamp, given the following code how would I modify streams `dataA$` and `dataB$` such that each of them emitted values in order of the timestamped value WITHOUT waiting until the entire stream has completed:

```
import { delayWhen, of, timer } from "rxjs";

const dataA = [{"data":"b","timestamp":6672},{"data":"c","timestamp":7404},{"data":"a","timestamp":7922},{"data":"b","timestamp":8885},{"data":"c","timestamp":9111},{"data":"a","timestamp":9245},{"data":"c","timestamp":10168},{"data":"b","timestamp":10778},{"data":"c","timestamp":11504},{"data":"a","timestamp":12398},{"data":"a","timestamp":12745},{"data":"a","timestamp":13648},{"data":"a","timestamp":14233},{"data":"a","timestamp":14943},{"data":"b","timestamp":15869},{"data":"c","timestamp":16043},{"data":"a","timestamp":16169},{"data":"a","timestamp":16242},{"data":"a","timestamp":17058},{"data":"b","timestamp":17885},{"data":"a","timestamp":18252},{"data":"a","timestamp":18711},{"data":"c","timestamp":18883},{"data":"b","timestamp":19618},{"data":"a","timestamp":20183}];

const dataB = [{"data":"b","timestamp":821},{"data":"b","timestamp":1357},{"data":"b","timestamp":2108},{"data":"b","timestamp":3001},{"data":"a","timestamp":3995},{"data":"b","timestamp":4475},{"data":"c","timestamp":5357},{"data":"c","timestamp":5373},{"data":"b","timestamp":6199},{"data":"c","timestamp":6207},{"data":"b","timestamp":6896},{"data":"b","timestamp":7410},{"data":"a","timestamp":8335},{"data":"a","timestamp":9191},{"data":"b","timestamp":10007},{"data":"b","timestamp":10703},{"data":"c","timestamp":11225},{"data":"c","timestamp":11453},{"data":"c","timestamp":12131},{"data":"c","timestamp":12599},{"data":"c","timestamp":13567},{"data":"a","timestamp":13726},{"data":"b","timestamp":14161},{"data":"b","timestamp":14224},{"data":"b","timestamp":14666}];

const dataA$ = of(dataA).pipe(
  delayWhen(() => timer(Math.random() * 5000)),
  ???
);
const dataB$ = of(dataB).pipe(
  delayWhen(() => timer(Math.random() * 5000)),
  ???
);

let lastTimestamp = -Infinity;
dataA$.subscribe(({ timestamp }) => {
  expect(timestamp > lastTimestamp).toBe(true);
  lastTimestamp = timestamp;
});

dataB$.subscribe(({ timestamp }) => {
  expect(timestamp > lastTimestamp).toBe(true);
  lastTimestamp = timestamp;
});
```

Follow up question: How can you extend that solution to dynamically support any number of data streams once a stream was created?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the issue is. How do your real Obserables look like? Do they continuously emit values? What is written in the question should already work if that is the case. Or do they emit arrays?

Comment: If you were to delete the `???` from each of the streams here this snippet of code will throw because `lastTimestamp` is shared between the two streams.

The issue is I have two distinct streams that return objects from differing time frequencies (e.g. TimeSeries data for two different IoT devices) but are both ordered. I want my streams to throttle/buffer such that they are ordered by in time but that I get all individual events.

Picture wanting to replay a series of events that happened across multiple devices in a simulated environment

Comment: So the emits of both Observables should be somehow ordered as a single stream?

Comment: No, the emits of both Observables should share state and buffer received values until the shared state dictates it can emit.

Comment: when does the shared state dictate that they can emit? Imagine the following timestamps: `dataA` emits `1`,  `dataB` emits `5` and afterwards `dataA` emits `3`. Should the value `3` be omitted or how should `dataB` know to wait for unknown values of `dataA`?

Comment: Great example. In that case `dataB` should wait (i.e. buffer values) until `dataA`'s next pending emission is greater than or equal to `5` or `dataA` completes. Keeping in mind that both streams are guaranteed to be ordered by timestamp. (Also add that `dataA` should be doing the same thing for `dataB`'s values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure *if* an *"RxJS-only"* approach using only pipe operators exists. However, here is how I would do it:

To make this reproducable, I created the following setup. This just pushes the elements of the arrays into the `Subjects` with a delay.

```
const dataA$ = new Subject()
const dataB$ = new Subject()

timer(0, 4000).subscribe(t => {
  if (!dataA[0]) return
  dataA$.next(dataA[0])
  dataA.shift()
})

timer(0, 3900).subscribe(t => {
  if (!dataB[0]) return
  dataB$.next(dataB[0])
  dataB.shift()
})
```

Just replace `dataA$` and `dataB$` with your own Observables and remove the `timer`s and subscriptions.

---

The resulting streams of data will be stored in two seperate Observables for which I created two `Subjects`.

```
const resultA = new Subject()
const resultB = new Subject()
```

It would be nice to just use `dataA$` and `datab$` and control how they emit by referencing each other in their pipes but this creates a circular dependency and I am not sure if this is managable.

Now we also need two buffers where the intermediate values are stored.

```
let aBuffer = []
let bBuffer = []
```

Let's subscribe to both data streams.

```
dataA$.subscribe(({ timestamp }) => {
  if (bBuffer.length === 0) {
    aBuffer.push(timestamp)
    return
  }

  while (true) {
    let first = bBuffer[0]

    if (first > timestamp) {
      resultA.next(timestamp)
      break
    } else if (timestamp > first) {
      resultB.next(first)
      bBuffer.shift()
    } else {
      resultA.next(timestamp)
      resultB.next(first)
      bBuffer.shift()
      break
    }
  }
});

dataB$.subscribe(({ timestamp }) => {
  if (aBuffer.length === 0) {
    bBuffer.push(timestamp)
    return
  }

  while (true) {
    let first = aBuffer[0]

    if (first > timestamp) {
      resultB.next(timestamp)
      break
    } else if (timestamp > first) {
      resultA.next(first)
      aBuffer.shift()
    } else {
      resultB.next(timestamp)
      resultA.next(first)
      aBuffer.shift()
      break
    }
  }
});
```

Both implementations are identical. Just `a` and `b` are changed. We basically wait for the other stream to have emitted a value. Until then, we push the values into the buffer.

When the a stream emits and the current timestamp is behind the first value of the buffer, we push the timestamp to the result. But if the buffer's first value lags behind, we use the `while` loop to *"catch up"* and emit all the lagging values in the process.

This seems to work fine for the example in the question.

```
let lastTimestamp = -Infinity;
resultA.subscribe((r) => {
  console.log("A", r, r > lastTimestamp)
  lastTimestamp = r
})
resultB.subscribe((r) => {
  console.log("B", r, r > lastTimestamp)
  lastTimestamp = r
})
```

Output:

```
/* ... */ 
B 5373
true
B 6199
true
B 6207
true
A 6672
true
B 6896
true
A 7404
true
B 7410
true
/* ... */
```

[image: Edit Rxjs playground (forked)]

Comment: So inspired by your answer I put together an operator that does this: https://gist.github.com/jshcrowthe/d0955bc3a315739781fdec50a06a4a17 it leverages the `heap` library on NPM to act as the buffer but maintains the sorted nature of the inputs. Main outstanding question for me is in the operator I posted, how do I make it responsive to any number of streams being added over time. Seeing as your response got me going in the right direction, will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**RxJS**

- **In your case like this** https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tfulqj

**Simple example**

```js
const { of, map, from, shareReplay, concatMap, endWith, NEVER, startWith, takeWhile, combineLatestAll, takeUntil, filter } = rxjs;

const dataA = [1, 10, 11, 15, 20];
const dataB = [0, 2, 3, 11, 21];
const dataC = [1, 3, 5, 9];
const max = Infinity;

const dataA$ = from(dataA);
const dataB$ = from(dataB);
const dataC$ = from(dataC);

const source$ = of(dataA$, dataB$, dataC$).pipe(
  map(endWith(max)),
  map(concatMap((x) => {
    const destroy$ = source$.pipe(filter((y) => x === y));
    return NEVER.pipe(takeUntil(destroy$), startWith(x));
  })),
  combineLatestAll(Math.min),
  takeWhile((x) => x !== max),
  shareReplay(1)
);

source$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```